# Upload images to Google Cloud instead of saving to disk (Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have a script which downloads certain images (<1 MB) from web and saves into local disk. Can I save it into a Google Cloud Storage bucket instead of my local system?

```
def downloadImage(url):
    try:
        print("Downloading {}".format(url))
        image_name = str(url).split('/')[-1]
        resp = urlopen(url)
        image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
        image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imwrite(current_path + "\\Downloaded\\" + image_name, image)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can employ the [GCS Python Client Library](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html) to programatically perform tasks related to GCS. The following code will upload a local file located at `/PATH/TO/SOURCE_FILE` to the GCS bucket `gs://BUCKET_NAME`

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket"""

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(
        "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
            source_file_name, destination_blob_name
        )
    )


BUCKET_NAME = "BUCKET_NAME"
SOURCE_FILE_NAME = "/PATH/TO/SOURCE_FILE"
DESTINATION_FILE_NAME = "DESTINATION_FILE"

upload_blob(BUCKET_NAME, SOURCE_FILE_NAME, DESTINATION_FILE_NAME)
```

Keep in mind that, in order to use the `upload_blob` method, it is necessary to have installed the GCS Python client library and to set up the authentication credentials. You can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) information about how to implement these steps.

Comment: Hi @Mayank Jain, could you accept my answer if you found it useful? Thanks!